# UITableView won't reload

Tags: uitableview, refresh, reloaddata

(Solved)
I have UITableView which is filled with some objects at the start. During the use the NSMutableArray for the tableView is getting some new items. But when I do `[myTableView reloadData];`, nothing happens.
myTableView is an IBOutlet in my header file.

Any ideas? :/

EDIT: Here are my methods for the tableView:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.mutableArrayFuerTableView count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cellFavoriten = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"favoritenCell"];
    NSString *favoritenString = [self.mutableArrayFuerTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cellFavoriten.textLabel.text = favoritenString;

    return cellFavoriten;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do some stuff when the row is selected
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

This is in viewDidLoad:

```
self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

self.favoritenArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:300];

defaultsFuerFavoritenTableView = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

mutableArrayFuerAnderenMutableArray = [defaultsFuerFavoritenTableView objectForKey:@"favoritenKeyUserDefaults"];

mutableArrayFuerTableView = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutableArrayFuerAnderenMutableArray];
```

Comment: I edited the post :) Sorry, the variable names are in German, hope you understand it anyhow.

Comment: das passt mir gut, uber Are you sure mutableArrayFuerTableView size is changing, can you post the code wich changes this array?, coz your table dataSource and delegate are correct.

Comment: It's not changing size, when this view is opened. I have another view controller, in which I save an array to NSUserDefaults. And when viewDidLoad is called in this VC, so when I open it with my Tabbar, this Array will be initizialized and filled by the UserDefaults. So it should change the data.

Comment: Ah, i solved it! My viewDidLoad wasn't called, so it didn't refresh. In viewDidAppear I have this now: `[self viewDidLoad];
    
    [self reloadTableView]` That solved it, thank you!